# Can we use Redis Stream as message broker with mass transit like mass transit with rabbitMQ or ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, redis, rabbitmq, masstransit, activemq-artemis

I want to use redis stream with mass transit like we can use mass transit with RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
x.AddConsumer(); // Assuming MessageConsumer is your consumer class

```
        x.UsingActiveMq((context, cfg) =>
        {
            var artemisOptions = configuration.GetSection("Artemis").Get<ArtemisMqOptions>()!;
            artemisMqOptions = new ArtemisMqOptions
            {
                QueueName = artemisOptions.QueueName,
                UserName = artemisOptions.UserName,
                Password = artemisOptions.Password,
                HostName = artemisOptions.HostName,
                Port = artemisOptions.Port
            };
        }
```

So instead of **UsingActiveMq** method I want to use or register Redis here,

is Mass transit support with redis stream message broker, If yes then how to use here?

Comment: Redis streams are not a supported transport for MassTransit.